# Non-decaying Harmonics in Vibration Signal

Tags: fft, frequency

I am analyzing vibration data collected by an accelerometer positioned in a stamp press machine. The fundamental frequency is around 10 Hz. The problem here is that when I take the FFT of the data I see harmonics of the fundamental frequency until 5000 Hz every 10 Hz (of course). I would expect some visible harmonics in low-frequency but with a decaying behavior until, at some point, it disappears. I attached 2 figures. The first one with a zoom from 0 to 1000 Hz and the other from 4000-5000 hz. Note that the Harmonics dominate the signal.

[image]

[image]

And here is a sample of the data:

[image]

I have being trying to convince myself that is normal but I can´t. What do you guys think? Can it be an effect of something that I should discard?

Thank you!

Comment: How is the accelerometer attached to the press?

Comment: Hey A_A, I don´t have this information yet. I will ask. but how the mount can influence the harmonics of my signal?

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at your time-domain signal, it looks a bit similar to a pulse train. And [the Fourier Transform of a Pulse train with distance T is a Pulse train with distance 1/T](http://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/the-dirac-comb-and-its-fourier-transform.html)

Hence, if you see a pulse every 10Hz, this corresponds to pulses every 0.1seconds in the time domain. That's what the time-domain signal looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Maximilian. So, do you agree that in order to analyze the "true" frequency content of my signal I will have to perform the fft in smaller chuncks of data where the impacts don´t look like impulse functions?